# TigerVNC - how to change quality?

Tags: linux, vnc, tiger

I'm using tigerVNC and I'm quite satisfied with it but I can't seem to be able to change the quality level. Appending arguments behind $vncviewer like QualityLevel=4 doesn't help, because it is choosing it automatically based on your bandwidth

```
CConn:       Throughput 1275 kbit/s - changing to quality 6
```

And quality 6 is way too much. More over I don't have 1275 kb/s but 1024 kb/s.

It renders incredibly slow. Can't use it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the parameter that turns this feature off is `-AutoSelect=0`

Manual says that

```
  AutoSelect     - Auto select pixel format and encoding. Default if           
                   PreferredEncoding and FullColor are not specified.          
                   (default=1)
```

but it also affects QualityLevel among others